# Multiple Personality Disorder (sock puppetry)

Tags: discussion

Let me put it this way:

Suppose that a person knows that they're the smartest physicist on earth. Such a person would find it very frustrating that their votes on questions and answers can be canceled by a single vote by another individual. What's worse, + votes for answers count for +10 reputation points, while - votes only count for -2, I think. To repair this deficit in the system design the only logical thing to do is to arrange to have multiple accounts.

Is there safeguards in the system for this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate further on your critic, at the moment it is very indirect imho. Greets

Comment: I think it's very clear what he means: SE sites can be rigged by using multiple accounts belonging to a single user in order to change overall votes?

Comment: LoL. I've been thinking about MPD but @Carl put it way better than I could. So basically you mean a person has two accounts with each upvoting the others answers and questions? Well, I think that ultimately whoever creates such feedback loops will get caught in their own act and that further tinkering with SE to deal with such issues is not necessary. As they say 'what a tangled web we weave ...'

Comment: This would get a better response on meta.stackoverflow.com (of course check first to see if other questions on that site give you the answer you're looking for, which I suspect is likely)

Comment: The answer is that there *are* safeguards in place, and if you think that they are being circumvented you can contact the team and ask them to look into it. There are various posts on the mother meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are, and we are watching you all the time. When sock-puppet is detected, all cross-votes are invalidated and so the reputation earned this way vanishes.

BTW, if one has real MPD, he/she can use multiple accounts -- the only crime is to vote on other personalities.

Comment: "if one has real MPD ..." LOL. That's a great answer +1

Comment: With the comments and answers, and with further cogitation, I'm convinced that MPD is a non issue. Thanks.